# Are Haar-Like features randomly generated for Viola Jones algorithm?

Tags: computer-vision, haar-classifier, viola-jones

Are the Haar-like features randomly generated in propotion to size, type and amount, in the computer vision algorithm Viola Jones?

I have the [paper](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eefros/courses/LBMV07/Papers/viola-cvpr-01.pdf) here and as I understand, AdaBoost is used to select the best Haar-like features that can separate the binary data. But it does not stand if the Haar-like features are randomly generated or pre-defined from initial start.